# Pocket casts like navigation bar background image

Tags: android, uinavigationbar, material-design, android-image

I was wondering how the pocket casts app creates its navigation bar background image. From what I notice they get the images from the podcasts you have subscribed and somehow create this image and set it as the nav bar background. Very cool effect!

Any tips in recreating something similar to this?

Thanks!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the steps from @Nikola answer:

```
    public static Bitmap createBitmap(int width, int height, List<Bitmap> bitmaps) {
    final Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAlpha(50);

    int currentWidth = 0;
    int currentHeight = 0;
    for (Bitmap scaledBitmap : bitmaps) {
        //draw the bitmap
        canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, currentWidth, currentHeight, paint);

        //update width
        currentWidth += scaledBitmap.getWidth();
        //update height
        if (currentWidth > width) {
            currentWidth = 0;
            currentHeight += scaledBitmap.getHeight();
        }
    }

    return newBitmap;
}
```

Main difference is that instead of a ColorFilter I ended up setting a transparency (with setAlpha).

If in the end you still want to rotate, simply call imageView.setRotation(degree) in the imageview that will hold your bitmap.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an empty `Bitmap` with the width and height of the header of the `NavigationView`.
2. Collect `Bitmap` images that you are interested and draw them scaled right next to each other on `Canvas`. You always draw from `0` to `scaledBitmap.getWidth()`, then `scaledBitmap.getWidth()` should be saved as next starting point for the next `Bitmap`. Perform the same logic for height. Limit the number of `Bitmap` you are going to draw to a certain number, for memory & performance reasons.
3. Take the `Matrix` of the `ImageView` that is part of your header view and rotate it for a certain degree
4. Apply `ColorFilter` with desired color to entire header view.

This also can be done rotating a drawable.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I followed your steps and posted the code as an answer!